# Dockerfile and chown permissions

Tags: docker, dockerfile, chown

I am new with the docker and I am trying to do a simple setup, which the scope is:

- create a home folder and give appropriate permissions

On host side:
I have a user called devel which I put into the docker group.
When I run 'groups devel' I get back the group docker. UID 1000 and GID 1000.
my subuid file:

```
devel:1000:1
devel:100000:65536
```

my subgid file:

```
devel:1000:1
devel:100000:65536
```

following a tutorial and setting the sysconfig file to start with that 'devel' as option for remapping.

I then created this Dockerfile:

```
   USER root
RUN groupadd -g 1000 devel

#Create the user with home directory
RUN useradd -d /var/opt/devel -u 1000 -g 1000 --shell /bin/bash devel
#Just for being very-very-very-very sure:
RUN chown -vhR devel:devel /var/opt/devel
#test with ls
RUN ls -ltr /var/opt/ 
User deploy
#test again by creating a file:
RUN touch /var/opt/devel/TEST.txt
RUN ls -ltr /var/opt/devel/TEST.txt

USER root

RUN ls -ltr /var/opt

USER devel
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

The result is that the directory which is created has group "devel" but the user owner is always the root.
I have **disabled** after 12 hours checking why the **SELINUX** for another reason (the reason was that id did not let me to use chown at all) but now I am stack and I know what else magic do I need to do.
The docker version is 18.09.1-ol ( oracle linux 7)

Hope someone has an idea.
Thanks

Comment: To somehow advance the topic, I found out that the in the end the subuid/subgid was not ok. That occured because of the mess that exists between various topics in internet regarding the uid/gid various issues people want to speak of.

Comment: It certainly needs host uid, host gid, to be equal to container uid, gid. and this subuid/subgid must be configured to do remapping this at most for basic level with one line. docker is good to start as well as with the same user that you are going to be using for container. at least for me seems to save a lot of noise as well. Disabling SELinux and invoking chown/chmod commands help at the most of the issues